# Can it be possible to handle the session from the PHP file in android apps

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, session

I have successfully logined into MySql database through android. Now i am trying to handle the session of a particular logined user. I have created the .php file with session handling process. And trying to carry session handling in android app through that .php file.
Can it be possible?
Any help will be appreciated. please help me or share me the link of tutorails containing this problem's solution. Thank You

Comment: some one please help me!

Comment: You could return the session id on valid login (php), store it somewhere (android), and then post it with every result.

Comment: Would  please share me the link. Or please make it clear! @JimL

Comment: Which part of it is it you need help with? I suggest trying, and posting questions you might have with relevant code.

Comment: u can follow this link for my code.......[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427151/session-handling-in-android-while-logging-into-the-server-side-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624440/sending-a-response-from-php-to-an-android-java-mobile-app) .This a question for getting response from php server to android u can change the php file and add the code which checks the `cookie` and read the answere it will give a hint on recieving response from `php`.